# Rendering exponential and periodic Julia fractals

Tags: java, algorithm, math, colors, fractals

I've read how to render Julia fractals [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425953/how-to-program-a-fractal). I'm pretty thorough with two-degree Julia sets with equations of form **f(z)=z<sup>2</sup>+C** but I don't know how to render complex Julia functions like **f(z) = e<sup>z</sup> - 0.65** and other complex functions which involve sine and cosine. How do we render these type of functions? Also, what color mapping should be used in exponential functions?

For instance I want to achieve something like the following image and others given on [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set).

[image]

**EDIT :**

Here is what I tried:

**ComplexNumber.java**

```
package plane.complex;

/**
* code>ComplexNumber</code> is a class which implements complex numbers in Java. 
* It includes basic operations that can be performed on complex numbers such as,
* addition, subtraction, multiplication, conjugate, modulus and squaring. 
*
* @author      Abdul Fatir
* @version      1.0
* 
*/
public class ComplexNumber
{
/**
* The real, Re(z), part of the <code>ComplexNumber</code>.
*/
private double real;
/**
* The imaginary, Im(z), part of the <code>ComplexNumber</code>.
*/
private double imaginary;
/**
* Constructs a new <code>ComplexNumber</code> object with both real and imaginary parts 0 (z = 0 + 0i).
*/
public ComplexNumber()
{
    real = 0.0;
    imaginary = 0.0;
}

/**
* Constructs a new <code>ComplexNumber</code> object.
* @param real the real part, Re(z), of the complex number
* @param imaginary the imaginary part, Im(z), of the complex number
*/

public ComplexNumber(double real, double imaginary)
{
    this.real = real;
    this.imaginary = imaginary;
}

/**
* Adds another <code>ComplexNumber</code> to the current complex number.
* @param complex_number the complex number to be added to the current complex number
*/

public void add(ComplexNumber complex_number)
{
    this.real = this.real + complex_number.real;
    this.imaginary = this.imaginary + complex_number.imaginary;
}

/**
* The complex conjugate of the current complex number.
* @return a <code>ComplexNumber</code> object which is the conjugate of the current complex number
*/

public ComplexNumber conjugate()
{
    return new ComplexNumber(this.real,-this.imaginary);
}

/**
* The modulus, magnitude or the absolute value of current complex number.
* @return the magnitude or modulus of current complex number
*/

public double mod()
{
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.real,2) + Math.pow(this.imaginary,2));
}

/**
* The square of the current complex number.
* @return a <code>ComplexNumber</code> object which is the square of the current complex number
*/

public ComplexNumber square()
{
    double _real = this.real*this.real - this.imaginary*this.imaginary;
    double _imaginary = 2*this.real*this.imaginary;
    return new ComplexNumber(_real,_imaginary);
}

/**
* Multiplies another <code>ComplexNumber</code> to the current complex number.
* @param complex_number the complex number to be multiplied to the current complex number
*/

public void multiply(ComplexNumber complex_number)
{
    double _real = this.real*complex_number.real - this.imaginary*complex_number.imaginary;
    double _imaginary = this.real*complex_number.imaginary + this.imaginary*complex_number.real;

    this.real = _real;
    this.imaginary = _imaginary;
}

/**
* Prints the complex number in x + yi format
*/
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return this.real+" + "+this.imaginary+"i";
}
/**
* Calculates the exponential of the <code>ComplexNumber</code>
* @param complex_number The input complex number
* @return a <code>ComplexNumber</code> which is e^(input complex_number)
*/
public static ComplexNumber exp(ComplexNumber complex_number)
{
    double a = complex_number.real;
    double b = complex_number.imaginary;
    a = Math.exp(a)*Math.cos(b);
    b = Math.exp(a)*Math.sin(b);
    return new ComplexNumber(a,b);
}
}
```

Here is how I tried to render:

```
for(int X=0; X<WIDTH; X++)
    {
        for(int Y=0; Y<HEIGHT; Y++)
        {
            ComplexNumber oldz = new ComplexNumber();
            ComplexNumber newz = new ComplexNumber(2.0*(X-WIDTH/2)/(WIDTH/2), 1.33*(Y-HEIGHT/2)/(HEIGHT/2) );
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<max_iter; i++)
            {
                oldz = newz;
                newz=ComplexNumber.exp(newz);
                newz.add(constant);
                if(newz.mod() > 2)
                    break;
            }
            float Brightness = i < max_iter ? 1f : 0;
            float Hue = i%256 /255.0f;
            Color color = Color.getHSBColor(Hue, Saturation, Brightness);
            img.setRGB(X,Y, color);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a question in your statement somewhere?

Comment: @hooknc Yes, and you need eyes to see the two question marks in the post but you won't see them when you are over-zealous to down vote.

Comment: I didn't down vote you.  Stackoverflow is a large community and just cause one person comments, doesn't also mean that they down voted you.  Your questions are overly broad and that is most likely why you got the down vote.  Do you mean how do you render the julia fractal algorithm in java using one of the ui libraries?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a specific programming question here.

Comment: @hooknc If you think the question is not about programming or overly broad then please do read the question I attached with it. My question is still much more specific and No, I am not talking about any UI libraries.

Comment: @AndrewArnold Yes, there it. Please read the linked question.

Comment: It *is* overly broad. It sounds like you are asking us to just write a program for you, and no one is going to do that. You need to try something yourself, and when you get stuck, come back and ask something specific.

Comment: @AndrewArnold I've tagged something called **math** and algorithm with the question. Did I ask for code anywhere? And by the way I've researched a lot and written article series on fractals. Don't assume I haven't tried. The thing is how can I try something I don't know.

Comment: If you've tried something, then post your code. Stack Overflow is for programming problems. If you want tips on pure math, there are other sites for that.

Comment: @AndrewArnold Have you even for once read the question I linked?

Comment: Yes, several times. But you haven't made any efforts to improve it.

Comment: Now it is on-topic, since there is a slight coding error in the exp-method that will lead to unexpected results.

Comment: The question has been answered. Please open this question so that people can share more of their knowledge on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the exp function, you used the value `a` again after changing it, but requiring it in its unchanged version. Replace with

```
public static ComplexNumber exp(ComplexNumber complex_number)
{
    double a = complex_number.real;
    double b = complex_number.imaginary;
    double r = Math.exp(a);
    a = r*Math.cos(b);
    b = r*Math.sin(b);
    return new ComplexNumber(a,b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton brother for going through the code and pointing this out. How trivial of me! :)

Comment: By the way, the colors in that picture seem to be just the classical 16 color EGA palette, repeated periodically. On second glance, it seems like a cycle of the first 8 colors of that with about 8 steps from one color to the next.

Comment: Yes, I got that. I can play with the colors now. :)